# PowerShell enter-pssession

Tags: powershell, iis, winrm

I'm using Windows 8.1. and I'm trying to execute commands on another Windows 8.1. by using PowerShell (enter-pssession or invoke-command). I usually have two types of error messages : one telling me that the access is denied and another one telling me that my Firewall does not allow an HTTPS exception. None of the computers is a server. I have already tried executing Set-PSSessionConfiguration -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI -Name Microsoft.PowerShell without any result whatsoever.

I have already tried de-activating my firewall and have already added other computers to my list of trusted hosts.

I always put an IP address after enter-pssession. Could this be the source of the problem?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S. Both computers have winrm, IIS and Apache.

Comment: Did you configure exceptions for PowerShell Remoting in the Windows Firewall on the host you want to access? Or disable the Windows Firewall entirely?

Comment: I have already tried de-activating my firewall and have already added other computers to my list of trusted hosts.

Comment: Are both hosts in the same workgroup and the same homegroup? Try connecting to the other host via `telnet`: `telnet <ip-address> 443`.

Comment: The 443 port is closed on the other computer. However, Winrm uses 5985 et 5986 as HTTP and HTTPS ports.

Comment: Well, are you able to connect to *those* ports?

Comment: I managed to connect to 5985, but not to 5986

Answer (score 0):

All you need to get started with remoting is available in the help:

```
 PS> Get-Help about_Remote_TroubleShooting -ShowWindow
```

If you're not in a domain, take a look at this section:

```
HOW TO CONNECT REMOTELY FROM A WORKGROUP-BASED COMPUTER
-------------------------------------------------------
[..]

When the local computer is not in a domain, the following procedure is required
for remoting.

1. Configure the computer for HTTPS transport or add the names of the
   remote computers to the TrustedHosts list on the local computer.
[..]
```

Comment: I have already tried de-activating my firewall and have already added other computers to my list of trusted hosts.